# Sed, awk or POSIX shell to populate an empty series of defines from a specification page

Tags: shell, awk, sed

I am often finding myself having to take a POSIX specification page (errno.h is a good example) copy paste them, and then fill in all the defines. How can I strip another file of its matching defines to the POSIX page so as to fill in the missing numerical field on the POSIX spec page and turn it into a library:

(Derived from http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/basedefs/errno.h.html)
The POSIX spec page for errno looks like this:

```
[E2BIG]
    Argument list too long.
[EACCES]
    Permission denied.
[EADDRINUSE]
    Address in use.
[EADDRNOTAVAIL]
    Address not available.
[EAFNOSUPPORT]
    Address family not supported.
[EAGAIN]
    Resource unavailable, try again (may be the same value as [EWOULDBLOCK]).
[EALREADY]
    Connection already in progress.
[EBADF]
    Bad file descriptor.
[EBADMSG]
    Bad message.
```

Then say one might have to fill these values in from a known library (mine, this one is already done) and make it all look something like this:

```
#define E2BIG           7       /* Argument list too long.              */
#define EACCES          13      /* Permission denied.                   */
#define EADDRINUSE      98      /* Address in use.                      */
#define EADDRNOTAVAIL   99      /* Address not available.               */
#define EAFNOSUPPORT    97      /* Address family not supported.        */
#define EAGAIN          11      /* Resource unavailable, try again .... */
#define EALREADY        114     /* Connection already in progress.      */
```

My `awk` and `sed` are mediocre so it's ending up taking me about an hour to do one of these simple library pages, then I still have to check it by eye.

Clarification of this question:

1. `[E2BIG]` becomes `#define E2BIG`
2. `#define E2BIG` becomes `#define E2BIG 7`
   '`E2BIG`' is matched and its value populated from a known library page
3. `#define E2BIG` becomes `#define E2BIG /* Argument list too long. */`
   The sentence on the line below gets turned into a /* C comment */ and concatenated with the line above it, which is the #define it corresponds to.

Comment: Could you clarify the question?  It's not entirely clear what you're trying to accomplish with awk/sed.

Comment: Tell us more about this "known library page" that contains the values (the `7` in your clarification). Is it a  local file? What format does it have? Can you include an example of it in your question as one of the inputs?

Comment: Then what's the difference between what you already have in `errno.h` and what you're trying to get as output?

Comment: But the values of the definitions depend on other macros, so you may have `#if defined(KERNEL) #define EOPNOTSUPP 102 #else #define EOPNOTSUPP  67 #endiif` so the error codes will depend on your compiler flags etc...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming here that the spec file is strictly alternating between spec strings and comments with only one line per comment as in the example.

First we load an array with the spec strings and values from the values file. Then from the spec file we check to see if we have the spec string in the array and if so print out the info (otherwise ignore it).

(The `$1 = $1` assignment just serves to trim extra spaces from the comment.)

Lastly, Mark Setchell makes an excellent point in his above comment, so careful about that.

```
$ cat none.awk
# reading values:
NR == FNR && $1 == "#define" && $3 ~ /[0-9]+/ { val[$2] = $3 }
NR == FNR {  next }

# reading spec:
NF == 1 && /^\[.*\]$/ { gsub(/\[|\]/,"",$0); s = $0; next }
s in val { $1 = $1; printf "#define %s\t%d\t/* %s */\n", s, val[s], $0 }    


$ cat values.txt
/*
 * Error codes
 */

#define EPERM       1       /* Operation not permitted */
#define ENOENT      2       /* No such file or directory */
#define ESRCH       3       /* No such process */
#define EINTR       4       /* Interrupted system call */
#define EIO     5       /* Input/output error */
#define ENXIO       6       /* Device not configured */
#define E2BIG       7       /* Argument list too long */
#define ENOEXEC     8       /* Exec format error */
#define EBADF       9       /* Bad file descriptor */
#define ECHILD      10      /* No child processes */
#define EDEADLK     11      /* Resource deadlock avoided */
                    /* 11 was EAGAIN */
#define ENOMEM      12      /* Cannot allocate memory */
#define EACCES      13      /* Permission denied */
#define EFAULT      14      /* Bad address */


$ cat spec.txt
[E2BIG]
    Argument list too long.
[EACCES]
    Permission denied.
[EADDRINUSE]
    Address in use.
[EADDRNOTAVAIL]
    Address not available.
[EAFNOSUPPORT]
    Address family not supported.
[EAGAIN]
    Resource unavailable, try again (may be the same value as [EWOULDBLOCK]).
[EALREADY]
    Connection already in progress.
[EBADF]
    Bad file descriptor.
[EBADMSG]
    Bad message.


$ awk -f none.awk values.txt spec.txt 
#define E2BIG   7   /* Argument list too long. */
#define EACCES  13  /* Permission denied. */
#define EBADF   9   /* Bad file descriptor. */
```